# How to get the GestureDetector's x and y axis coordinates in Flutter

Tags: flutter, coordinates, gesturedetector

Currently, I am building a Pinterest clone app and I really need your help. Actually, I've spent almost an hour searching for the answer but none of the solutions given worked. So what I need is just to determine the x and y axes of the place where the user pressed through the Gesture detector. Can anyone help me, please...

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should not be using a `GestureDetector` here but a `Listener` widget instead. As a listener can give you the **global position** of where the user presser, or a **relative position** to where the widget pressed starts.

Here is some example code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class GetPositionExample extends StatelessWidget {
  const GetPositionExample({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Listener(

      // This will report a PointerDownEvent whenever the user presses the screen.
      // If you want updates as the user moves their finger across the screen,
      // use onPointerMove instead.
      onPointerDown: (PointerDownEvent event) {
        // Global screen position.
        print("Global position x:${event.position.dx}, y:${event.position.dy}");
        // Position relative to where this widget starts.
        print("Relative position: x:${event.localPosition.dx}, y:${event.localPosition.dy}");
      },

      // You should also be aware of these Listener methods,
      // if any of them is more suited for your use-case:

      // onPointerMove: (PointerMoveEvent event) {},
      // onPointerUp: (PointerUpEvent event) {},
      // onPointerCancel: (PointerCancelEvent event) {},
      // onPointerHover: (PointerHoverEvent event) {},
      // onPointerSignal: (PointerSignalEvent event) {},

      child: Container(
        color: Colors.blue,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/2,
      ),
    );
  }
}

// Some code to run the above example
class App extends StatelessWidget {
  const App({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(home: Scaffold(body: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
      children: const [
        GetPositionExample(),
      ],
    )));
  }
}

void main() => runApp(const App());
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear. What do you mean by `determine the x and y axes of the Gesture detector`

If all you need is know if user swipped right, left or down here is an example

```dart
  GestureDetector(
          onVerticalDragUpdate: (details) {
    int sensitivity = 8;
            if (details.delta.dy > sensitivity) {
              // Down Swipe
              
            } else if (details.delta.dy < -sensitivity) {
              // Up Swipe
             
            }
          },
          onHorizontalDragUpdate: (details) {
            // Note: Sensitivity is integer used when you don't want to mess up vertical drag
            int sensitivity = 8;
            if (details.delta.dx > sensitivity) {
              // Right Swipe
             
            } else if (details.delta.dx < -sensitivity) {
             
              //Left Swipe
            }
          },
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I need to get the coordinates of the place where the user pressed by gesture detector

Answer (score 0):

You can use [rect_getter](https://pub.dev/packages/rect_getter) for your desire. And implement as follows:

```
    var globalKey = RectGetter.createGlobalKey();
  Offset _tapPosition;
  var dx;   //for x-axis
  var dy;   //for y-axis

RectGetter(
              key: globalKey,
              child: new Expanded(
                child: new InkWell(
                  onTap:  _handleTapDown,
                  onTapDown: _handleTapDown,
                  child: Center(
                    child: Container(
                      child: Utility.imageFromBase64String(imagename),
                      //  backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF20283e),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

_handleTapDown function

```
void _handleTapDown(TapDownDetails details) {
final RenderBox referenceBox = context.findRenderObject();
setState(() {
  _tapPosition = referenceBox.globalToLocal(details.globalPosition);
  dx = double.parse(_tapPosition.dx.toStringAsFixed(2));
  dy = double.parse(_tapPosition.dy.toStringAsFixed(2));
  print(_tapPosition);
 
});
}
```